# File Descriptor error when opening in "wb" mode

Tags: python, pickle

I am reading in some data from a csv. Storing them in a dict. Creating two SymbolInfo objects and also storing these in a dict. I then store each of these dicts in a tuple, and attempt to dump this tuple using pickle.

```
symbols = ["EURJPY", "EURGBP"]
tup_0 = {}
tup_1 = {}
for symbol in symbols:
    sym_info_obj = symbol_info(symbol)
    sym_mtsim_obj = SymbolInfo(sym_info_obj)
    tup_0[symbol] = sym_mtsim_obj
    main_direc = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "\\" + "Code and Data"
    symbol_file = f"1M-{symbol}-1S.csv"
    full_file = main_direc + "\\" + symbol_file
    data = pd.read_csv(full_file)
    data["Time"] = data["Date"].astype(str) + " " + data["Timestamp"]
    data = data.drop(["Timestamp", "Date"], axis=1)
    tup_1[symbol] = data

tup = (tup_0, tup_1)

full_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Code and Data", "test.pkl")

with open(full_path, "wb") as fh:
    pickle.dump(tup, fh)
```

This is the code i am using, where symbol_info() is a function which returns a SymbolInfo object.

However, when i try to create a file handle to pass into the pickle.dump method, i either:

1. Get a file or directory not found error.
2. Have created the file manually and then get a Bad file descriptor error
3. Try to use regular "w" mode - which opens the file, but then get a type error saying i must write a string not bytes.

Both the .py file, the .csv and .pkl file (when i manually created it) are all under the same folder

Comment: The "file or directory not found" error means there's no `Code and Data` subdirectory. Opening a file for output will create the file, but it won't create directories. You need to use `os.mkdir()` to create the directory.

Comment: Also, remember that `os.getcwd()` doesn't return the directory containing the script. It returns the user's current directory. There's no need to join that, since relative pathnames are resolved relative to the cwd automatically.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause "bad file descriptor". Google "python bad file descriptor" to see the common reasons for that error, such as trying to read from a file opened for writing and vice versa, or trying to use a file handle after closing it.

Comment: @Barmar I have looked everywhere and the most common problems are as you have mentioned. I only use the file for pickle.dump() so I dont know how it could be a reading problem, and i am using a with statement to open the file so I dont know how I would be closing it prematurely.

Comment: That's why I don't think that error could be happening from this code. You described 3 different problems, they can't all be happening with the same code.